# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following line of code:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Which is creating the following error...

`SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`

I can't work out how to identify what's causing the error though.

Any ideas?

Here's the data...

```
{
    "element_type": "paint",
    "edit_element_id": "2117",
    "paint_id": "15",
    "paint_editable_data": "zwibbler3.[{\"id\":0,\"type\":\"GroupNode\",\"fillStyle\":\"#cccccc\",\"strokeStyle\":\"#000000\",\"lineWidth\":2,\"shadow\":false,\"matrix\":[1,0,0,1,0,0],\"layer\":\"default\"},{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"PageNode\",\"parent\":0,\"fillStyle\":\"#cccccc\",\"strokeStyle\":\"#000000\",\"lineWidth\":2,\"shadow\":false,\"matrix\":[1,0,0,1,0,0],\"layer\":\"default\"},{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"BrushNode\",\"parent\":1,\"fillStyle\":\"#cccccc\",\"strokeStyle\":\"#000000\",\"lineWidth\":10,\"shadow\":false,\"matrix\":[1,0,0,1,0,0],\"layer\":\"default\",\"points\":[17,21,17,22,17,24,17,28,18,34,37,55,49,59,70,61,89,56,92,55,93,54]},{\"id\":3,\"type\":\"PathNode\",\"parent\":1,\"fillStyle\":\"#e0e0e0\",\"strokeStyle\":\"#000000\",\"lineWidth\":2,\"shadow\":false,\"matrix\":[1,0,0,1,-14,-85],\"layer\":\"default\",\"textFillStyle\":\"#000000\",\"fontName\":\"Arial\",\"fontSize\":20,\"dashes\":\"\",\"smoothness\":0.3,\"sloppiness\":0,\"closed\":true,\"arrowSize\":0,\"arrowStyle\":\"simple\",\"doubleArrow\":false,\"text\":\"\",\"roundRadius\":0,\"commands\":[0,150,100,6,200,150,200,100,6,150,200,200,200,6,100,150,100,200,6,150,100,100,100,7],\"seed\":36934}]",
    "paint_image_data": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALwAAAB1CAYAAAD0rovXAAASHklEQVR4Ae1dCXBW1RW+BAKJNAwihMWgkYkN+1JgRGAEBKQtISIVcBoQRGiKhBadQXQ07XQoVhwQtLiwVGSzUEAgwGgAIVgMyCbLsAlllzVSFSmLhPT7Hv/LvCwk77285V/Omfly33Lfued+9+T+d3v3KSUiDAgDwoAwIAwIA8KAMCAMCAPCgDAgDAgDwoAwIAwIA8KAMCAMCAPCgDAgDAgDwoAwIAwIA8KAMCAMCAPCgDAgDAgDwkA4M1ApnDMneSuTgXtwt34A9QzH+jU9pJKzpeBcsWvfMmKwizh8sJeQc/YlQ1VXoFsgrIvQSTkPZTkBbEB4CAg6sevwlZGTjkBqAMxYVgC5CPN5QcRXBqKR+iPA4wHcZ7QmNjZW1a1bV8XHx2th8WP9nM9cuHBBnT9/vhDGc/346tWrRvU8PgmsCOBzhD8Bvotdh38flqffwfrpuP77O9yTy+4zkIQkRgDPAHX05GrXrq06dOigOnbsqIWNGjXSbzkSHj16VG3ZskXl5uZqYV5enlHvRZzMBmYCR4w3vD624/CPwcjscgzthftryokjt51loDXUvQr0A7RyTUpKUr169dLQsmVLZ1MrR9uePXtUdna2hiNHCn28AI99DPwV2FWOCldu23H4HFjSpRxrNuJ+13LiyG1nGGgGNeOBJ6guJiZGpaamqsGDB6sWLVrwku+yd+9eNW/ePJWVlaWuXbum27MMB5nAPv2CF6Edh/8fDIstxzg26O4qJ47crhgDCXicjv40EMU2+aBBg1R6erpi8yUYhc2c6dOnq/nz56tAm/8W7JwL0PFPe2GzHYfnz5IZsaPbjN5IjxMDAl4EXgJio6OjVVpamsrIyAhaRy9eYHT8adOmqQULFqifftL6sqwgXwfeAAp/Aoo/58S5HacUh3eCeXs62H96D9B6nCkpKWrcuHGqYcOG9rT5/NSpU6fUxIkT1apVq3RLjuJgJOBa/08cXqc6uMMaMG8q8AzNbNy4sRo/frxq3749T0Netm3bpjIzM9XBgwf1vMzGwRjgB/2CU6E4vFNMuqfnYaj+CEhkh3TMmDFqxIgRqnJlToWEj+Tn56uZM2eqqVOn6h3b48jdb4HNTuZSHN5JNp3XNRoq3wSqtGrVSk2ZMkU5PX7uvMkV08jx/Oeff17t3r2bim4CLwB/54kTEuWEEtHhOAOsvtlWfxuoMnz4cLV06dKwd3ayyH9o5pV5Zt4BckAuHPlJc7OGp7GyxAAkWBQuCWAT5slq1aqpSZMmqT59+lhUER7RV65cqcaOHas3cZYgV2ziVGiJgh2Hv4JEzYyxc7HS14CIeQZYHnT2p2rUqKE++OAD1a5dO/NPh2HM7du3q2HDhqkfftD6rwuRRTq92ZHCEozYadIUzhOX0Fb0AmcARawxMAnRn4qLi9MmZyLd2UkdOeBEFTkhNwA5si12HN7sVLA4vLVi4fjzC5xImjVrlvJ67Ys1U72NTS7ICbkhRwC5siV2OgJNkNKjJlJjnL+YiCdRbvPJpkzU5MmTVY8ePYSTYgwkJCRoE2xckAbh4sQvgGM8sSJ2HJ5vygw0mchpxPvKZNxIjXY/Mr4O+BmXBzz77LORykO5+W7SpIm6efOm2rp1K1smKcAi4PtyHzREsNNp/TmeP2TQUdYhR2n6AVllRYrge9WQd9ZUbVmrc+KlUiU7RRI5DBYUFGgTb+vWsY5QO4BOwHWemBE77PJXgSM1LCwzchWRegIsWJGiDEzD6ajExETFIbhAx6xoDDkrwcDly5e1odrjx4/z3jtABg/MiJ1OK2vtXDPKA3FiEa4EpBNblLRUnI6qWrWqevfdd8XZi3JT5hkrBnJG7sghQC5NiZ02PBVfANJMpXA7Ep2eRi0BtAHV25cj9m88cv4pUJ2Lpnr25A+giBUG6tSpo1USOTk5fIy9/DkAWx5lip0ango/Ad4uU3PJmwm4xC52rZK3Iu7K+8hxnS5duqihQ4dGXOadyjC5I4eQOgA5LVfstOF1pfxn+ScwQL9gMtyMePyP5JtTkShPItOL+bO8du1aVa9evUjkwLE8nzt3TvuFZLse0h9gK+KOYreGp0K+njUYWM8TC/Iw4nI4qYqFZ8IlKqcL32JmXnnlFXF2B0qVFQa5DAi51aZk9QvFw4o4PHXdAPoCVsfaOYY6A4g0+TMy3IDT5QMHmp3KiDSKrOeXXAaWYTTA0+T4jlKRJo1RaV2ccOSmkfGiiWO+x/iyiXjhECUJmdgfFRUVvXr1asVJFBHnGDhw4IDq3bu3unXrFldTNgVKXfNV0Rpet/g8DnoBHL2xIi8h8h+sPBDCcSfA9ugBAwaIs7tQiKxAyC05Bsh1qeJUDa8r/wUOcoAy21F65EBYgJBLPrn0M1ylFTL2FV7Rq7Rx40Zta7twzaif+eJ2gBy1wd439Kk2wO7i9jhVw+t6d+KgH8C2vVnhP90cgCM34SqZyFgl7hvDPRtF3GGA3JJjCH2KnJcQp2t4PYGncPARYEU/x5W6AvynCSd5EJk5iLeXojZt2qQ4YSLiHgMXL15UnTt3VtevX+coYmPgsDE1p2t4XTebJ9xmwYqwGcQJLXbuwknYR4nq16+fOLsHpcoKhVyTc6BE/9BKDWzH3L/hIXZMrQg34+kIsCMc6lIdGTgLxHEdd3JycqjnJyTsP3TokLaBLIxlq6E+ULjkwK0aXieGQ46z9ROTYSPEY01vpeNrUrXn0TjzF8cxYnF277gn14FxefoQy6BQ3HZ4JvQ7oHAvtcKUyz5gD3s5ULXsaEF/lzPRqn//IpwHvdHhYKCBc60M9Dy53aTR0+EuB1yxz2UFVuS/iNwaOGnloSCJyxWRZ/EeZtSOHTsUdyEQ8Y4B7nLQtm1bbtbKziubNdockRc1PHPJhWJcTnCAJxbkbsQ9AXwB/BHgistgF/4qdQH+AUR16tRJnN2HEmMFQ+5ZBgB9TxOvHJ6JXQI4G3uaJxaFndipAGv6YHN+csgJt7FANsBfpRxAI7l79+44FPGDAQP3v9TT96pJo6fHkG8+/Rtg7V0R4WzaZuBfwFLAzj8SHrMlHDrtAdCbuwH3AKXKhg0b1AMPPFDqPbnoLgPHjh1T3bqxeFQewCZmgR8OTwP4W7MWiOWJQ8LhP/4CnAuA5zzWQ/26lVlgPK4JF60/CuhOft/ty2X/5Zgwt4IW8Y8BbinOyShIY+BQFZ9MYbOEs7EfA5UdsoEdE6I8YdPK+I9g/IfQj9nnaAGwBieaA5aldWv2t0X8ZIBlwBdtINyz0DeHpwFZQDowiyceSi2kRTR1O81mzdh6E/GTAZZBwOFbwo4F7HD5KRzJeNVPA9xMm5+NFPGXAUMZJNMSvx2eNkwAXgbstK35fNBKqH57KWgJtWGYoQwS+XgwODzteB3g0N4GgKMvYSHygrb/xWgogwa0JlgcnrbsAx4FOAIyBsgFQtr5a9ViV0HETwYMZaAVRjA5vM7LaRy8BXDoMmSdn7tiBbZ31vMloQ8MsAwCO5Rpo4HB6PBGWkLJ+U/C8NlAGjMgzk4WgkOMZeHXxFNFmeCamt8AfYH2QHXAa/kWCbLP8RmwDjgC6FJQvXp1tW8fW2kifjPAockrV67QjLDZm5nLFDjpxBlRPSztuCKNak5GbQLo3HTyXQBX4pUmBVWqVFFHjhj/B0qLJte8YIBDk9xXHlKpihcJepAGF2wR+8tJiysZ+Y+gQ//n0EP9n4RvWl8FqG89QCffDITd0CnyFFESLg5vttDosGxrE64KPzkpEhwMsCwCNXxQDUsGBztiRVgzEOyjNCFLPt60CVnbw81wY1mIw7tTuvk3btzg62XuaBetphlgGbAsIPn8Iw5PFpwXLkFWly5pgfPaRaNpBgxloBWGOLxp6ixFPMPY3KxfxF8GDGWglYk4vDvlcZxqT5065Y520WqaAUMZHOdD4vCmqbMU8RBjy8STJc5ciWwoA61MxOFdoVntoVpZWuAOuVa0GspAKxNxeCvsmY+7nVF37eLqAxE/GTCUgVYm4vDulMbXUJvHt+W5VYSIPwyQ+8COBdymg2UibXiXioIvrnAlpeKe8CL+MGDgnmXBMhGHd7EoPqXuzz7jwkoRPxgwcK+VBW0I1fXwfvBnNc14PCCbqVplzaH4fm+m6lA2QkoNd6vN4dT2J59wu3sRLxkg54GlHTlIV9s5mOlLp5UsuCfzqHrx4sXupSCaS2XAwLlWBnokcXidCXdCevrl7du3K36GRcQbBsg1OYfwkzdFahtxeHfLgC9SzmESH374IQMRDxgwcE3utZdZ9WSl06oz4V74IFTLZyvd47eIZr8+W1nEiAg/OYz8L8N3Q9X06dMjnAr3s0+OyTU5B8h9EZEavggdrp20gmb59Lxr9N5W7Men513OUsiq3w3LF1+7dk1NmTIlZDMR7IaTW3JMrgFyXkKkhi9BiWsXkqB5f1RUVPTq1atVkyZNXEsoEhUfOHBA9e7dW926dYvvVXLv/1I3BZJRGu+8gwXwNgpEZWZmqoICbWmHd6mHcUrkkpySW3IMlOrsvKltMMkDEU8Y4GZOQ86cORNXv3591bx5c08SDfdEFi1apObOncts8jW+/oD21jYvFBdp0hRnxP3zJ5HE4ri4OO1TLIb9y91POQxT4DurPXv2VJcvc45Jc/YlZWVTmjRlsePOPRbIMhbQuHHj3EkhgrSSw4CzcxiyTGcnLdKk8cc5uD576IkTJ6rXrFlTydf+7BUCZ1TnzJnDhy8CvwaKzKryRnGRJk1xRrw7T0VSK7hZ//Lly1XTphxYEDHLwP79+1Xfvn31TZYex3NZZp6VJo0ZltyJwwJ6h7tiPffcc/rPsjsphZlWNmHIWWBHsXeQPVPOThqkSeOvM/B1qF999913DQ4fPqz69OmDHfvlR7esIuEQ5KhRo9TOnTsZbQcwENC20eOF8kQcvjyG3L3PgsoGBh89evSu/Px81bFjR3dTDHHtkydPVgsXLmQu+AWW7oGQ56ZEHN4UTa5G+h7atwNpW7dujbr//vtlFvYOdC9btkyNHz+ed28CbLdb3gdFHJ70+S/HYEIe0Hv9+vXqoYceUgkJCf5bFUQWfPnll2rkyJH6bGoGTCvyYodZU8XhzTLlfjzW8jUwPf5wdna26ty5s6pbt677qYZACnv27FFDhw5VV69epbVvAvx6uy0Rh7dFm2sPrYXmZIw+NOcCs/bt26sGDRq4llgoKOarekOGDNFHsdh4T6+I3eLwFWHPnWc5xNYELzE0XbFihUpMTFTJycnupBTkWleuXKk1YwKfnFwCcwcBpkdkSsueOHxprPh7jUv+PgbiMWrTjttN/Pjjj9roDZYW+2uZR6nzA2SvvfaamjBhgv4xsveR9DCAndUKiTh8hehz7WGuHV4NXAJ6Ysw5auPGjVpn9u67+Una8BUMz6phw4bpe/nQwccAfwIcWU8tDh/cvrMV5q0DuuP1tZpcBssPHrdp00aFW23POYgZM2ao0aNHq2+++YalchxIAZYCjok4vGNUuqboNDTPBurhp74NNwhds2aN1q6/9957XUvUS8Xbtm1Tw4cP19YUBb6nyvz2Bf7jtB0yj+00o+7qewzq3wMaMZmUlBRtiXHDhg15GnLCz9FMnDhRrVq1Srf9KA5GAmv0C06H4vBOM+q+vhgk8SLwEhAbHR2t0tLSVEZGhqpdu7b7qTuQQl5enpo2bZpasGCBvv8jB9hfB94AtLewHUimVBXi8KXSEhIXE2DleOBpICo2NlYNGjRIpaenB63j09G5b8z8+fP1SSSOSM0FMgE23VwXcXjXKXY9gWZIgY7/BFOKiYlRqampavDgwapFixa85Lvs3btXzZs3T2VlZenbaNAmvqFER9/HE69EHN4rpt1PpzWSeBXoB2jlmpSUpHr16qWhZcuW7ltgSIHLAbhEgjB8SY9Di5xj+CtgeeGXQb3tQ3F429QF7YPc/2YE8AxQR7eS7fsOHTpoE1gMGzXS+r367QqHHD/fsmWLys3N1UI2XwzCV/A48jITOGK47vmhOLznlHuWYDRSegTgMlriPqBQ2Obn4rT4+HgtLH6sn/OBCxcuKG5jp8N4rh8HFnYV6sfBSWBFAJ8j5AZJvos4vO9F4JkBXJDTFegWCJ1einkeenMC2IAwKDfEF4dHyUSo3IN81w+gnuFYv6aHpOdsKThX7BrfQBIRBoSBYGLg/9jYtJnVySp3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
}
```

Is it the size that's the problem maybe?

Comment: First question: why you use jquery.parseJson instead of JSON.parse, second: Can you show data

Comment: Can you show your data?

Comment: Could you provide the JSON contents you are trying to parse?

Comment: Have you checked it in http://jsonlint.com/?

Comment: Checked in jsonlint.com and it passed...

Comment: No need to parse it in that case: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/N4Hjc/1/

Comment: You could have a point there... I'm picking up someone else's code so struggling to see what they've done.

Comment: This error can also occur if response is blank

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you are trying to convert a text string into a JSON data object.

You should probably be doing the following:

- instead of using `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`, rather just use `JSON.parse(data)`.
- The error you mentioned indicates you are passing in an empty string "" as your value of data. So check the value that is being passed in to the parse method.
- The data object you mentioned that you are passing in will always result in an error since it's already in a JSON format.

The parse method is intended to do the following conversion.

`JSON.parse("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")` returns `{hello:'world'}`

If you are trying to convert in an object into a string, you can try this:

`JSON.stringify({hello:'world'})` returns `"{\"hello\":\"world\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. When you define the JSON in the script, the double quotes should be represented by \" , not " .

Answer (score -1):

In my case i was also facing that same error in **React-native** but after look into my code i found that .. .**my API hit URL was not complete** .. and after that.. my problem was resolved :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What do you mean by "my API hit URL was not complete"?

Comment: yeah @William actually in my case i have found the issue that.. the URL by which i am making hit to the server was not fully entered by me into my code so from there i got that error.. and once when i was looked into that and entered correct url then that problem was resolved

Answer (score -5):

Maybe you can do with the eval method :

```
if (data !== null) {
    var json_obj= eval("("+data+")"); //jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    //just for check the the keys     
    var keys = Object.keys(json_obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
    };
}
```